# TACL How to use multiple Arguments

Tags: hp-nonstop, tandem

I was wondering if we have any TACL experts out there can can help me answer probably a very basic question.

How do you inject multiple arguments into you routine.

This is what I have currently so far

```
[#CASE [#ARGUMENT / VALUE job_id/number /minimum [min_job], maximum [max_job]/
                               otherwise]
   |1|#output Job Number = [job_id]
   |otherwise|
   #output Bad number - Must be a number between [min_job] & [max_job]
   #return
]
```

I have been told you need to use a second #ARGUMENT statement to get it to work but I have had no such luck getting it to work. And the PDF guides don't help to much.

Any ideas/answers would be great

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `#CASE` statement isn't required if your arguments are positional and of one type (i.e. you know what you are getting and in what order). In that case you can just use a sequence of `#ARGUMENT` statements to get the arguments.
In your example `#ARGUMENT` accepts either a number in a range or anything else - the `OTHERWISE` bit. The `#CASE` statement then tells you which of those two you got, 1 or 2.

`#ARGUMENT` can do data validation for you (you may recognize the output from some of the TACL routines that come with the operating system).

So you can write something like this:
`SINK [#ARGUMENT / VALUE job_id/number /minimum [min_job], maximum [max_job]/]`

The SINK just tosses away the expansion of the #ARGUMENT, you don't need it since you only accept a number and fail otherwise.

Comment: Oh ok. I did try to do just an Argument before but I must of formatted it wrong as I kept getting an error. I may give it ago once I get the rest of my routine working to a point where it's doing what i want it to

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way but idk if it is the best way to do it.

It seems that for one an Argument statement needs to always be in a #CASE statement so all I basically did was mirror the above and just altered it for text rather than use integer.

If you know of any other/better ways let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

It find it best to use CASE when you have multiple types of argument
input to process. Kind of mocked up how I would see multiple argument
types being used in the context that you shared with the CASE
expression:

```
?TACL ROUTINE

#FRAME

    #PUSH JOB_ID MIN_JOB MAX_JOB
    #SETMANY MIN_JOB MAX_JOB , 1 3
    [#DEF VALID_KEYWORDS TEXT |BODY| THISJOB THATJOB SOMEOTHERJOB]

    [#CASE
        [#ARGUMENT/VALUE JOB_ID/
            NUMBER/MINIMUM [MIN_JOB],MAXIMUM [MAX_JOB]/
            KEYWORD/WORDLIST [VALID_KEYWORDS]/
            STRING
            OTHERWISE
        ]
    | 1         |
        #OUTPUT VALID JOB NUMBER = [JOB_ID]
    | 2         |
        #OUTPUT VALID KEYWORD = [JOB_ID]
    | 3         |
        #OUTPUT VALID STRING = [JOB_ID]
    | OTHERWISE |
        #OUTPUT NOT A NUMBER, KEYWORD, OR A STRING
        #OUTPUT MUST BE ONE OF:
        #OUTPUT A NUMBER IN THE RANGE OF: [MIN_JOB] TO [MAX_JOB]
        #OUTPUT A KEYWORD IN THIS LIST: [VALID_KEYWORDS]
        #OUTPUT OR A STRING OF CHARACTERS
        #RETURN
    ]

    #OUTPUT
    #OUTPUT NOW WE ARE USING ARGUMENT [JOB_ID] !!!
    TIME

#UNFRAME
```